# Accessing the Parse server in Android without a master key doesn't give authorization

Tags: android, parse-server, bitnami

When I access my server with the following it works:

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: xxx" \
  -H "X-Parse-Master-Key: yyy" \
  -H "Content-Type: text/plain" \
  -d '{"score":1337,"playerName":"Sean Plott","cheatMode":false}' \
  http://xx.xx.xx.xx/parse/classes/Inventory
```

But when I use the following, it doesn't:

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: xxx" \
  -H "Content-Type: text/plain" \
  -d '{"score":1337,"playerName":"Sean Plott","cheatMode":false}' \
  http://xx.xx.xx.xx/parse/classes/Inventory
```

I get this error instead:

```
{"error":"unauthorized"}
```

It worked perfectly fine earlier. I had changed a few settings and updated to the latest Parse Server version and then it stopped working, along with all the other apps related to it.

The web version works, suggesting that the REST API key was fine. I can access everything perfectly through the Dashboard too. The only problem is when I access it with Android, which can only give an Application Id for identification.

Might I have changed a setting wrong that blocked this? I don't think I changed anything, though there is the small possibility I didn't close a bracket or commented something out on the server.js file.

Comment: Did you add a client key to your index.js perhaps? When you initialize parse-server? I know when parse-server launched, they made that optional (though recommended). It's not considered "secret" since it can be decompiled from your app, but you absolutely shoould not ever put your master key into the mobile client.

Comment: It appears I removed all `clientKey` from the code, but the problem is still there.

Comment: I'd recommend using the client key. How is your server initialized? With or without a client key? Show you redacted index.js please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's brought up here: https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server

> The client keys used with Parse are no longer necessary with Parse Server. If you wish to still require them, perhaps to be able to refuse access to older clients, you can set the keys at initialization time. Setting any of these keys will require all requests to provide one of the configured keys.
>
> - clientKey
> - javascriptKey
> - restAPIKey
> - dotNetKey

What happened was that I had `restAPIKey` inside my config file, so it required any one of the other four keys as well. The new update forced my app to use `clientKey` or remove `restAPIKey` from the config.